# Error Connecting to SQL Server database with C# Applet

Tags: c#, sql-server, applet

I'm trying to link a C# applet to a local database i have installed. I am unsure if I'm using the connection statement `WebSecurity.initializeDatabaseConnection` properly.

Below is the code of the _AppStart.cshtml file:

```
@{
    //WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Data Source= WITPB03DMBB\\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=callCenterFinal;uid=resnav;pwd=;pooling=false; Connect Timeout=45", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", autoCreateTables: true);

    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("callCenterFinal", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", autoCreateTables: true);

    //WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("callCenter", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", autoCreateTables: false);
    //WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("callCenterDatabase", "ccUsers", "id", "email", true);
    //WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Data Source= WITPB03DMBB\\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=callCenterFinal;uid=resnav;pwd=;pooling=false; Connect Timeout=45;", "System.Data.SqlClient", "UserProfile", "id", "email", true);
}
```

The commented out lines are the ones I have tried, if I use the line:

```
//WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Data Source= WITPB03DMBB\\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=callCenterFinal;uid=resnav;pwd=;pooling=false; Connect Timeout=45", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", autoCreateTables: true)`
```

This line gives me an error that the connection succeeded, however there is no data on the other side of the pipe.

I took out the pwd field in the above text.

Comment: "an error that the connection succeeded"?

Comment: there is data that it should recieve, the pipe shouldnt be empty